# Cannot start old project on mac, on win it works

Tags: javascript, npm

npm i leads to following and i don't know what to do with it
try reinstal node, python, pyenv and still have this issue
i'm using mac m1pro
the same node version on the windows run this project without issues
i'm stack with this issue and run the project, i don't get it how it works on windows but on mac it crush

```
> node-sass@4.14.1 install /Users/nicetea/work/repos/planit-frontend/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

`Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/darwin-arm64-83_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/darwin-arm64-83_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. `

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /Users/nicetea/work/repos/planit-frontend/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js


Building: /Users/nicetea/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node /Users/nicetea/work/repos/planit-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/Users/nicetea/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/nicetea/work/repos/planit-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.21.3 | darwin | arm64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:383:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/nicetea/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node" "/Users/nicetea/work/repos/planit-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/nicetea/work/repos/planit-frontend/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.21.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
```

Comment: Looks like it's expecting Python 2 to be the system Python, and you have 3 installed.  This `gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?` is trying to call the Python 2 syntax of "print"

Comment: Node Sass moved to Dart instead of Python, perhaps you can upgrade the project? https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass/

Comment: i can't update project, i have to run it with this node-sass version, i know that one colleague runs this project on M1 air but he doesn't know how it works

Answer (score 0):

i reinstall all.
I use brew to install nvm and this was the issue. Because it didn't install arm64 version of node. After reinstalation everything works good.